# Rails assets:precompile only one asset?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline

Currently we have a Rails application but I have one question regarding the assets precompilation.

Each time that I edit one file (stylesheet or javascript file), we have to run:
`bundle exec rake assets:precompile`
...and then upload everything again, even those files that didn't changed at all.

Is there a way to compile only the edited files and the manifest.yml file?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

i also had such a question, googled a lot and found one gem called: **[guard-rails-assets](https://github.com/dnagir/guard-rails-assets)**

It compiles the assets within Rails 3.1 application whenever those change.

For example, you can do this:

```
# compile ONLY when something changes
guard 'rails-assets', :run_on => :change do
  watch(%r{^app/assets/.+$})
end
```

Check it out

Answer (score 2):

I think no and unneccessary because all js files are compiled to one file as and css files.
If you changed only one file - you changed such combined files. 
But, if you want to update resource file such as images, I think, you may, only place it in right directory under public/accets

Comment: I see your point, but if I change only a CSS it should compile ONLY the CSS files, no need to precompile ALL my 4MB of images and Javascript, right?