# Precompiled assets and Non-compiled assets

Tags: ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline

Can I use assets that aren't pre-compiled along with assets that are inside a rails application?

I have separate CSS files uploaded through a web interface and don't want to precompile my assets everytime I add a new CSS file because a) that would be way too manual of a process and b) the styles all go to one page, like a theme, and so use the same class names.  These CSS files do not require any processing as they are simple CSS files.

The CSS files are in a sub-folder of the assets folder inside the public folder: `public/assets/styles/`.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible.

If i'm not wrong this SO link is very close to what you were trying to achieve

[Rails assets:precompile only one asset?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9713464/rails-assetsprecompile-only-one-asset)

Hope it helped !